# Toolbar Has Automatically Set Margins

Tags: android, android-studio, toolbar, material-design, android-appbarlayout

I made a Material Design Toolbar, but the end product results in a toolbar with margins on the top, left, and right sides of the toolbar. How do I make it so that the toolbar doesn't have these margins?

My Code:

app_bar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar         

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/primaryColor"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">
```

MainActivity.java (AppCompatActivity is extended)

```
public Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar" />
```

I don't understand why the toolbar/appbar is not fitting the entire width of the screen. Please help!

Comment: Can you post the entire xml where the toolbar is included? Maybe the parent layout is applying some sort of padding/margin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured out the answer.

Android was applying these default lines of code in the activity_main file:

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Removing those 4 lines at the top of the activity_main file helped to remove the padding from the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Post the whole xml code I think your RelativeLayout has padding